# How do I fix the URL for the <TAB>-triggered automatic documentation lookup in the Common Lisp REPL?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop, clisp, tab-completion

## SYNOPSIS

I'm trying to become competent at using Lisp.  Though I'm very comfortable with
the command line and various REPLs for other interpreters (i.e. `python`,
`irb`/`pry,` `perl -d`), I keep feeling like an absolute newbie when it comes
to Lisp, for some reason.

In the Common Lisp REPL (`clisp`), when I use the  key at the end of a
function name, it seems to be trying to provide me with reference information
about that function.  This sounds damn useful.. if it actually worked.  Below
is what actually happens when I do this.  As far as I can tell, it seems to be
looking up the functions on a URL that doesn't (or no longer) exist/s.  Perhaps
the HyperSpec has moved?  What's the right way to fix this?  What should I do?

## ADDENDA

### How I'm running Lisp

```
$ uname -a
Linux bob 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ clisp --version
GNU CLISP 2.49 (2010-07-07) (built on toyol.buildd [127.0.1.1])
Software: GNU C 4.8.2 
gcc -falign-functions=4 -W -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wpointer-arith -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wmissing-declarations -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-format-nonliteral -O -falign-functions=4 -DENABLE_UNICODE -DDYNAMIC_FFI -DDYNAMIC_MODULES -I.  -lreadline -lncurses -ldl /usr/lib/libavcall.so /usr/lib/libcallback.so  -lsigsegv libgnu_cl.a 
SAFETY=0 TYPECODES WIDE_HARD GENERATIONAL_GC SPVW_BLOCKS SPVW_MIXED TRIVIALMAP_MEMORY
libsigsegv 2.10
libreadline 5.2
libffcall 1.11
Features: 
(READLINE REGEXP SYSCALLS I18N LOOP COMPILER CLOS MOP CLISP ANSI-CL COMMON-LISP LISP=CL INTERPRETER SOCKETS GENERIC-STREAMS LOGICAL-PATHNAMES SCREEN
 FFI GETTEXT UNICODE BASE-CHAR=CHARACTER WORD-SIZE=64 PC386 UNIX)
C Modules: (clisp i18n syscalls regexp readline)
Installation directory: /usr/lib/clisp-2.49/
User language: ENGLISH
Machine: X86_64 (X86_64) bob [127.0.1.1]
```

### Lisp-related packages currently installed on the system

```
$ aptitude search lisp | grep '^i'
i   clisp                           - GNU CLISP, a Common Lisp implementation   
i   clisp-doc                       - GNU CLISP, a Common Lisp implementation (d
i A common-lisp-controller          - Common Lisp source and compiler manager   
i   dh-lisp                         - Debhelper to support Common Lisp related p
```

### What I get when I try to look up a function:

```
$ clisp -q
[1]> (write-line <TAB><TAB>

WRITE-LINE is the symbol WRITE-LINE, lies in #<PACKAGE COMMON-LISP>, is accessible in 11 packages CLOS, COMMON-LISP, COMMON-LISP-USER, EXPORTING,
EXT, FFI, POSIX, READLINE, REGEXP, SCREEN, SYSTEM, names a
;; connecting to "http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Data/Map_Sym.txt"...connected...HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
;; "Date: Tue, 04 Oct 2016 02:34:52 GMT"
;; "Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)"
;; "Content-Length: 333"
;; "Connection: close"
;; "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
;; ""
;; "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">"
;; "<html><head>"
;; "<title>404 Not Found</title>"
;; "</head><body>"
;; "<h1>Not Found</h1>"
;; "<p>The requested URL /projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Data/Map_Sym.txt was not found on this server.</p>"
;; "<hr>"
;; "<address>Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at www.ai.mit.edu Port 80</address>"
;; "</body></html>"
;; connecting to "http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Data/Symbol-Table.text"...connected...HTTP/1.1 200 OK...45,322 bytes
;; SYSTEM::GET-CLHS-MAP(#<IO INPUT-BUFFERED SOCKET-STREAM CHARACTER www.ai.mit.edu:80>)...978/978 symbols
 function.
ANSI-CL Documentation is at
"http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_write-str_m_write-line.html"
;; connecting to "http://clisp.cons.org/impnotes/id-href.map"...connected...HTTP/1.1 302 Found --> "https://clisp.cons.org:80/impnotes/id-href.map"
;; connecting to "http://clisp.cons.orghttps://clisp.cons.org:80/impnotes/id-href.map"...
*** - PARSE-INTEGER: substring "" does not have integer syntax at position 0
The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop
Break 1 [2]>
```

Comment: See the clisp manual on [`DESCRIBE`](http://clisp.org/impnotes/debugger.html#describe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this article](https://eggplant.pro/blog/fixing-double-tab-help-in-gnu-clisp/) should help you.

In essence you have to set up your `CUSTOM:*BROWSERS*` list, so clisp knows how to open the documentation.

In your `.clisprc.lisp`

```
(setf CUSTOM:*BROWSERS* '(
   (:CHROMIUM "/usr/bin/chromium" "~a")))
(setf CUSTOM:*BROWSER* :CHROMIUM)
(setf CUSTOM:CLHS-ROOT "http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/FrontMatter/")
```

But you have to have chromium installed on your system. But you get the idea.

Comment: Very clear.  Thank you.  It's been slightly frustrating finding resources that feel like the "next" thing I need to know.  Everything seems to be either "Here's an entire chapter on how to call a function.", or "These three lines illustrate a fun variation on the common toy problem everyone knows about except you where you solve the three-body problem in a parallel universe with a coefficient of friction equal to how macros are magic."

:)

Comment: Also, thanks for the working URL.  It looks like 's/Data/FrontMatter/'.  I.. guess they rearranged the website at some point recently?

Comment: @JonCarter Welcome! TBH I use `sbcl` :) I am not very familiar with `clisp`. My environment (emacs) provides nice shortcuts and documentation. For example it I want to see the sbcl documentation for a function I will type `C-c C-d d` (which is equivalent to `describe`) and if I want to see the hyperspecs I will type `C-c C-d h` :)

Comment: Thank you. I've heard about how ideal a lisp environment Emacs is.  But I'm a long-time vim user, to the point where even vile seems somehow too odd.  I've tried a few times to dig into Emacs, but I haven't yet gotten past training my fingers on any but the more basic commands, much less figured out how to put the thing into the correct major/minor mode, or whatever voodoo you weirdos call it.  :)

So, with respect to what I'm sure is Emacs' ability to turn loaves into fishes, I thought I'd use what I know (vim), at least until I can "get" enough lisp to compel me further..  So `sbcl`, huh?